# Apache hangs with Django / Matplotlib app

Tags: python, django, apache, matplotlib

new StackOverflow user here.  I need help with an Apache freezing problem.  I have a WAMPServer setup on Win 7 64-bit and am working with python / django / mysql / mod_wsgi / matplotlib, experimenting with dynamically rendered images.  I am using Apache to serve static files.

I am trying to plot data from a MySQL database. My views.py file is below.  When I invoke the function "view_Stats" by visiting the appropriate web page, this calls the "CreateFig" function to create and save .png files to a directory that are subsequently served by Apache.  It works fine initially, but it seems as if a maximum of 8 calls can be made to the "CreateFig" function before Apache just hangs. I have to restart Apache at that point, but it takes a while (minutes) for it to restart.

Looking at the Apache error logs (see below) shows an error related to Apache child processes that requires Apache to force it to terminate.  I suspect some sort of memory leak / error, but I'm pretty new at this and can't troubleshoot well; I've Googled this and looked around on StackOverflow, no joy.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
[Tue Mar 11 17:01:07.550093 2014] [core:notice] [pid 2820:tid 404] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Tue Mar 11 17:01:07.551093 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2820:tid 404] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3528
[Tue Mar 11 17:01:07.856093 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3528:tid 324] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Mar 11 17:04:53.233893 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2820:tid 404] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Mar 11 17:05:23.248293 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2820:tid 404] AH00431: Parent: Forcing termination of child process 3528
```

The Code from views.py is below:

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect

from rwjcnlab import settings
from clientele.models import UserProfile
from reports.models import EEG, LTM, EMU, AEEG

import os, datetime
import numpy
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import gc


# CREATE VIEWS HERE
def view_Stats(request):
    UID = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id = request.user.id)
    StatsEEG, StatsLTM, StatsAEEG, StatsEMU, start_date = ReportNumbers(UID.id)

    # Create figures
    CreateFig(StatsEEG, 300, 50, 'EEG', 'b')
    CreateFig(StatsLTM, 100, 10, 'LTM', 'r')
    CreateFig(StatsAEEG, 15, 3, 'AEEG', 'y')
    CreateFig(StatsEMU, 25, 5, 'EMU', 'c')

    return render_to_response('view_Stats.html', {
        'StatsEEG': StatsEEG,
        'StatsLTM': StatsLTM,
        'StatsAEEG': StatsAEEG,
        'StatsEMU': StatsEMU,
        'start_date': start_date,
        'user': request.user,
    })

def CreateFig(Stats, ymax, yinc, figname, c):
    nAll    = tuple(x[1] for x in Stats)
    nUser   = tuple(x[2] for x in Stats)
    xlabels = tuple(x[0].strftime("%b%y") for x in Stats)

    ind     = numpy.arange(len(xlabels)-1.4,-0.4,-1)    # the x locations for the groups
    width   = 0.8                                       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence

    plt.ioff()
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=72, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    p1 = plt.bar(ind, nAll[1:], width, color=c)
    p2 = plt.bar(ind, nUser[1:], width, color='g')
    plt.title(figname+' Volumes at RWJUH')
    plt.xticks(ind+width/2., xlabels[1:])
    plt.yticks(numpy.arange(0,ymax,yinc))
    plt.legend( (p1[0], p2[0]), ('Total', 'User') )
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static/'+figname+'.png'))

    fig.clf()
    plt.close(fig)
    gc.collect()

    return
```

Comment: that gc.collect is a code smell (I'm hoping this is just you trying anything but I have yet to see a case where doing that in python is helpful and feels like a Java/C# action)  I'd suggest trying to run this under the Django dev server (and possibly adding an import pdb; pdb.set_trace() in create figs so you can single step stuff.

Comment: Also, in my experience, Windows can be squirrelly with file stuff, as in blocking process 2 from accessing a file if process 1 is still using it; have you tried generating different filenames each time you call the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because you're trying to connect to a (presumably non-existent) X-server when you use matplotlib.  If you do have X running on your webserver, you probably still want to avoid using an interactive backend for matplotlib

(*Edit*: Just saw that you're on windows. Obviously, it's not that mattplotlib is trying to connect to an X-server when run on Windows, but I'd be willing to bet that your problem is still related to using an interactive backend and matplotlib trying to connect to    the graphical display.)

If you want to use matplotlib without interactive plots (i.e. without needing an X-server), then you need to explicitly use a non-interactive backend.  (e.g. `Agg`, `pdf`, etc)

First off, remove `from pylab import *`.  That's a really bad idea for a huge number of reasons (hint, `min` and `max` aren't what you think they are, among other things).  Also, you don't seem to be using it.  You're already accessing matplotlib functionality through the pyplot interface and `numpy` though the numpy namespace.

Next, *before* you do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` (or before you do `from pylab import *` if you decide not to remove it), do:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot # etc...
```

Now matplotlib won't try to connect to the X display everytime you make a new figure.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! You were right and it's working reliably now!